# Eclipse: Within a plug-in, how to access another plug-ins preference store?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plug-in with a checkbox in the plug-in's preference page.
This checkbox is used for enabling and disabling an editor, which is being launched from this plug-in.

However, the problem is, I would also like to be able to enable and disable this 'editor-launch' from another plug-in, by having actions which change the value of the checkbox in the above mentioned preference page.

Here's the problem, how do I access that local preference store from another plug-in?

I've tried things like..

```
View myView = (View) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("ViewID");
```

But this '`myView`' always seems to be null.. And also, what would I do with the view since it's the Plug-in I want.

```
Platform.getBundle('bundleName')...
```

Same here, want the Plugin, not the bundle corresponding to is.

No matter what I try nothing seems to work.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Please refer to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferences_pluginaccess
2. Using .getPluginPreferences(). For example, there is a plugin class "com.xxx.TestPlugin" which extends org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.Plugin, in order to get access to the preferences of TestPlugin. The plugin code could be below:

```
public class TestPlugin extends AbstractUIPlugin {
private static TestPlugin plugin;

public static final String PREF_TEST = "test_preference";
/**
 * The constructor.
 */
public TestPlugin() {
    plugin = this;
}

 /**
   * This method is called upon plug-in activation
 */

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the plug-in is stopped
 */
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.stop(context);
    plugin = null;
}

/**
 * Returns the shared instance.
 */
public static TestPlugin getDefault() {
    return plugin;
}
}
```

To access the preference of TestPlugin, the code could be:

```
TestPlugin.getDefault().getPluginPreferences().getDefaultBoolean(TestPlugin.PREF_TEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or have a look at this answer: [Writing Eclipse plugin to modify Editor Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343288/writing-eclipse-plugin-to-modify-editor-preferences/6382827#6382827)

Answer (score 0):

This [thread recommend](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg29942.html) the use of a Service tracker:

```
ServiceTracker tracker = new ServiceTracker(ToolkitPlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getBundleContext(),
                                            IProxyService.class.getName(), null);
tracker.open();
proxyService = (IProxyService) tracker.getService();
proxyService.addProxyChangeListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

Prefs stores are found per plugin. This is one way to get a prefs store for the plugin whose activator class is ActivatorA.

IPreferenceStore store = ActivatorA.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

If you want another plugin to refer to the same store, perhaps you could expose some api on ActivatorA for it to get there, e.g.

public IPreferenceStore getSharedPrefs() {
    return ActivatorA.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
}

The second plugin would find the shared store by doing this

IPreferenceStore sharedPrefs = ActivatorA.getSharedPrefs();

Good luck.